# Encoding&compression of URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, string, compression

How to easy encode and "compress" URL/e-mail adress to string in PHP?

String should be:

1. difficult to decode by user
2. as short as possible (compressed)
3. similar URLs should be different
   after encoding
4. not in database
5. easy to decode/uncompress by PHP script

---

ex. input -> output,
stackoverflow.com/1/ -> "n3uu399",
stackoverflow.com/2/ -> "ojfiejfe8"

Comment: Are you trying to create some kind of url shortener?

Comment: I need this for many problems ex. e-mailing confirmation  by clicking example.com/confirm.php?id=ii3ru38jd39 <- encoded & compressed e-mail adress

Comment: As I have written in my answer, I would strongly suggest associating the obfuscated alias with the emails in your email storage (database, flat file, whatever). What you're trying to achieve is called security through obscurity and is generally considered bad practice (you try to apply a secret algorithm and the whole system breaks if someone manages to get his hands on it): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: Those confirmation links are not encoded or compressed. That are just random, once valid tokens that are stored on the serverside to get the association what they authenticate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very short but you could [zip](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) it with a password and encode it using [base64](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php). Note that [zip is not too safe when it comes to passwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Encryption), but should be ok if your encrypted value is intended to have a short lifetime.

Note that whatever you do, you won't be able to generate a somewhat safe encoding unless you agree to store some unaccessible information locally. This means, whatever you do, take it as given that *anyone* can access the pseudo-encrypted data with enough time, be it by reverse engineering your algorithm, brute-forcing your passwords or whatever else is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could make your own text compression system based on common strings: if URL starts 'http://www.', then the first character of the shortened URL is 'a', if it starts 'https://www.', then the first character is 'b'...(repeat for popular variants), if not then first letter is 'z' and the url follows in a coded pattern.

The if next three letters are 'abc', the second letter is 'a' etc. You'll need a list of which letter pairs/triplets are most common in URLs and work out the most popular 26/50 etc (depending on which characters you want to use) and you should be able to conduct some compression on the URL entirely in PHP (without using a database). People will only be able to reverse it by either knowing your letter pair/triplet list (your mapping list) or by manually reverse-engineering it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation that may or may not fulfil your needs:

**Input/Output:**

```
test@test.com    cyUzQTEzJTNBJTIydGVzdCU0MHRlc3QuY29tJTIyJTNC             test@test.com  
http://test.com/ cyUzQTE2JTNBJTIyaHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnRlc3QuY29tJTJGJTIyJTNC http://test.com/
```

**Code:**

```
function encode ($in) {
    return base64_encode(rawurlencode(serialize($in)));
}

function decode ($in) {
    return unserialize(rawurldecode(base64_decode($in)));
}
```

*shrug*

You need to be more specific about your inputs and outputs and what you expect from each.

You could also use gzcompress/gzuncompress instead of serialize/unserialize, etc.

Answer (score -2):

if you have access to a database then you could do a relational lookup i.e. there will be 2 fields, field one holding the original URL and the second holding the compressed URL.
To make the second URL you could do something like the following

```
$str = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";

$str = explode(" ", $str);
$len = 5;

for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
{
    $pos = rand(0, (count($str) - 1));
    $url .= $str[$pos];
}
```

This is just an idea that i have thought up, code isn't tested

Comment: I think you would be very likely to get collisions (i.e. the same code for different urls). Also you don't need to split the string into an array - you can access string offsets using [] anyway. Also it would be better to call count() outside the loop and store the result.